# Using '-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch' hides content while scrolling/dragging

Tags: css, webkit, mobile-safari

as the title says I'm having the problem with content getting hidden while scrolling/dragging the content when using the CSS property `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`.

For a basic understanding, here is my markup

```
<div class="page">
   <div class="section_title">Title</div>
   <div class="items">
      <div class="item">...Text and Image...</div>
      <div class="item">...Text and Image...</div>
      <div class="item">...Text and Image...</div>
   </div>
   <div class="section_title">Title</div>
   <div class="items">
      <div class="item">...Text and Image...</div>
      <div class="item">...Text and Image...</div>
      <div class="item">...Text and Image...</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.page {
    width: 320px;
    height: 366px;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

The code itself works good, I can scroll through the content but everything that is inside of a items div get's hidden while I'm scrolling/dragging. Anyone came across this issue and solved it or is it just standard behavior of Mobile Safari to save memory and there is nothing we can do about it?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Have you tried putting the elements into memory?

If not, try putting .items in memory using the css `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);`

You may want to go higher or lower in the nesting depending on performance, ie applying the translate to .page or .item. This will increase the memory used which can get crashy but it helps the browser redraw everything.

Anyways, hope that helps!

Comment: Still got the problem and the solution didn't work for me https://codepen.io/laserpen/pen/Nogmex

Comment: I find this partially works, but has bad rendering artefacts - the absolutely positioned elements stutter as I scroll

Answer (score 4):

This probably has to do with a bug in webkit. 
If you have any "position: relative" or absolute your code should work just fine.